# Include a file from a parallel directory in php

Tags: php

I have 3 folders: `main`, `core` & `ajax`. But `core` and `ajax` folders are inside the `main` folder. `init.php` file is inside `core` folder and `ajax.php` file is inside the `ajax` folder:

```
main
├── ajax
│   └── ajax.php
└── core
    └── init.php
```

How can I include `init.php` from `ajax.php`? This doesn't work:

In `ajax.php`:

```
include 'core/init.php';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
include __DIR__ . '/../core/init.php';
```

or, with older versions of PHP:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../core/init.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
include __DIR_.'/../core/init.php';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this way:

```
include '../core/init.php'
```